# JPA Extending Entity class - Parent key not found

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, mapping

I have a problem with JPA mapping. I still get "ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated-parent key not found". My problem depends on that fact that I include class A and B from jar file, and I cannot change it, only overriding.

My mappings look like:

-- First table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_A", sequenceName = "SEQ_A")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DOMAIN")
public abstract class A {
      @Id
      @Column(name = "A_ID")
      private Long id;
}
```

-- Second class with second table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
@DiscriminatorValue("C")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "B_A_ID")
public class B extends A {
    @Column(name = "B_FIELD")
    private String bField;
}
```

And my class with a problem. I want to add new field to B class/table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
@DiscriminatorValue("X")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "B_A_ID")
public class BExt extends B {
     @Column(name = "B_MY_FIELD")
     private String newField;
}
```

Sorry for my english. Could you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add a field to existing table, but you use `JOINED` inheritance.

You need `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
@DiscriminatorValue("X")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)    
public class BExt extends B {
     @Column(name = "B_MY_FIELD")
     private String newField;
}
```